# Is "logicalising" a valid word?

Tags: meaning, suffixes, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

Is *logicalising* a valid word, if the meaning was to make something supposedly 'illogical', logical?

Comment: I might prefer *logicizing/logicising* but perhaps that means something else

Answer (score 4):

"Logicalise" already exist as a word, and it already means something other than the definition you listed. It means "to reason, to think, to use or apply logic", without the connotation of trying to make something illogical into something logical. For example, see here:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logicalizing

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logicalize

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/logicalize

The word you might be looking for is "**rationalise**" or its various synonyms.

> **rationalise**: attempt to explain or justify [something] with logical,
>   plausible reasons, even if these are not true or appropriate. *(from ODO)*

Comment: I think you should give the M-W definitions. One _denotation_, never mind connotation, of 'logicize' seems relevant.

Answer (score -4):

'Logical' is an adjective which you have then verbalised.
I would say 'logicate' is the correct verb from the noun, 'logic'.

And, since it is available in English, it is quite valid.
I know of several books that have used 'logicate' within the past five years.

'Logicate' is similar to calculate, but 'calculate' is a matter of arithmetical logic whereas 'logicate' is the process which uses pure logic, rather than numbers.

Comment: ELU deals with accepted English usage. A few instances of the use of a candidate word may be nothing more than an error. There needs to be some authoritative endorsement of a usage to show that the candidate has actually been accepted into the lexis, and a reasonable answer on ELU would not lack evidence.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth I preferred not to quote the books (six of them) in which the word occurred because they are all authored by myself. The word is chosen deliberately to translate the Greek word λογιζομαι, logizomai, which has a large bearing on New Testament theology but had no suitable English equivalent, until now.

Comment: You can't confer wordness unilaterally.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth But language is not a static thing. It develops, in the hands of those who wish to develop it.

Comment: But neither is language a free-for-all. The NASB version renders 'λογιζομαι'
consider (6), considered (2), counted (1), counting (1), credit (1), credited (9), credits (1), dwell (1), maintain (1), numbered (2), propose (1), reason (1), reckoned (2), regard (4), regarded (3), suppose (1), take into account (3), thinks. {[BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/greek/3049.htm)} And it's generally regarded as the most accurate. 'Develop' often becomes 'do your own thing', which can soon become 'obfuscate' or even 'promulgate untruth'. Before you came clean, ...

Comment: 'I know of several books that have used 'logicate' within the past five years.' was disingenuous. As you well know.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I know of those books. I cannot un-know of them.And they exist, now, on bookshelves.Genuinely.And when one word is translated by 17 possibilities, it shows that the word is not understood properly.

Comment: But you were violating the Gricean maxim of quantity by not saying you wrote them. Just as if, when someone says 'Could you lend me $5 till tomorrow?' you answer 'I've got $2" when you've actually got $200. Not telling the whole truth and thereby implying a distorted reading. 'Rationalising'.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth . . .  just looking up "Gricean". Back in a minute . . .