# How to verbify "logic"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, verbs

If someone wants to turn a conversation into political way, we call it "politicize"

If someone wants to turn a conversation into drama, we call it "dramatize"

What do we call it when someone wants to turn a conversation into logical conversation?

Comment: Say *logicalise*.    https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412431/is-logicalising-a-valid-word

Comment: What _is_ a logical conversation?

Comment: It's not clear in what form you want to use "logic".

"a logical conversation" isn't the same as "a conversation about logic". Which are you Asking about?

English doesn't allow your comparisons… partly because English simply doesn't recognize "turn (anything) into (political or any other) way…"

Your "politicize" seems to mean "make political"; your "dramatize", "make dramatic".

"Politicize" and "dramatize" seem comparable; "political" and "dramatic" are not.

Comment: I would say "engineer".  Dan Hicks, Master of Engineering (EE)

Comment: You *reason* things out or *think* things through.

Comment: Or you could just *logic* your way to a conclusion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about logicalize? From M-W:

> **[logicalize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logicalize)**: lo*gicize*
>
> *[logicize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logicize)*: to make logical : convert to logical form, e.g. *logicized* the argument

While **logicalize** is obviously similar to @Noah's answer, "to **logicalize** a conversation" seems a natural way to describe "the turning of a conversation into a logical conversation".

Answer (score 1):

I think "logicize" may be the correct word.

This dictionary.com entry seems to back that idea up (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/logicize)

The definition states "to make logical; give logical form to".

The definition could be talking about the application of logic abstractly or to something specific.

Comment: Sorry but if you don't know, what follows can't be an Answer.